GCP MQL global filter on multi query widget dashbaord
I created dashboard with widgets containing multiple queries, for eg max and avg value from metric. When I apply global filter (pinned on top of dashboard) it only applies to first query found, and makes the second disappear from widget.
Is there a way of making it work for both, or maybe a way to combine 2 queries from 2 different metrics in one query?
I tried passing them in array but only actions I could perform after were join - not good since I want 2 separate lanes. Sorry for trivial question but I found hard finding any help so far, will appreciate any help.
fetch gcp_compute_instance
| metric 'metric.name("myMetric1")'
| fitler ...
| join (
    fetch gcp_compute_instance
    | metric 'metric.name.max("myMetric2")'
) 

This doesn't work of course, what I need is another value series displayed next to first one

Can you clarify how is this is related to promql?

I can use mql or promql to build widgets in gcp. Finally I convert them to json and use terraform to deploy them. Was looking for promql examples also, no result
